# Cygwin R usability

Tags: r, windows, gcc, cygwin, package

It may seem to be an odd question, but really want to get rid of some doubts as to the strange situation Cygwin R is in. The official site ([R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Cygwin)) says that Cygwin 64bit is completely not supported and that Cygwin's BLAS library is flawed ("Do not use Cygwin’s BLAS library: it is known to give incorrect results."). But the Cygwin package repository site ([Cygwin R repository site](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86/R/)) keeps maintaining updated R (even 64bit). According to my personal experience with Cygwin R (v3.1.3 64bit), it seems that it works well, including the installed packages (usually built from source without error). Given the fact that there are many people out there using Cygwin R (at least there are a number of related questions on stackoverflow). Therefore I ask here whether Cygwin R should not be used for production, and if so why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't, because it's *not supported* ... if it breaks, you get to keep the pieces.

Comment: You do realize there's a perfectly good Windows version of R?

Comment: @Harry, yes, I understand the MinGW built R is what the official site provides, but it does not seem so "perfect" in terms of peripheral uses such as building packages and working in coordination with other Linux tools. Indeed they provide the tool chains (in Rtools*.exe), but I prefer a system-level basic Linux tool set (e.g. GCC, Tex) and let R, Perl, etc share it. This is exactly what Cygwin does. Also Cygwin has lots of common Linux libraries, they can be installed and used out-of-box. Conversely, manually installing these dependencies would be a toil.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should just be running Linux. :-)

Comment: @Harry thanks, you are right probably. I once tried that, just missing some Windows specific applications kept me from running Linux solely. Another option is to run a virtual machine, which is clumsy too. So far Cygwin seems to be a neat answer except for the cautions about the **R usability** which makes me upset. One thing interests me in particular is that why/how the Cygwin maintainers manage building and updating the Cygwin version of R: it should be totally pointless if these caveats are real.

Comment: It is possible that the developers of R just don't trust Cygwin as a platform and so have chosen not to support it; I certainly don't trust it, for various reasons not worth going into here. But if the Cygwin developers say their port of R is reliable, and you trust them, well, it becomes a matter of opinion (hence the close votes). Any specific concerns, e.g., the BLAS library, may or may not have been addressed, you might like to ask the people providing the port about it. (Actually if you posted a new question here on just on the objective aspects of that particular issue it might be OK.)

Comment: @Harry, very reasonable answer, thanks still.

Comment: Here is the feedback by the Cygwin developer (https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-08/msg00284.html). According to the reply, their port seems to be safe.